# DataGrid AlternatingItemStyle After e.Item.Visible = False

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

We have an ItemCommand that makes a DataGridItem invisible.  This is breaking the alternating color scheme that we have applied.  Is there a way to re-apply the style without rebinding or manually setting each DataGridItem's BackColor property?

Comment: you can do zebra client side : http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a total hack, but since you only seem concerned with the BackColor, I'd probably ditch alternating item style altogether and create an image with two colors, one on top of the other, of the right color. Set it to stretch horizontally and repeat vertically as the background of the grid itself. Since you can control the height of your items, it's just a matter of creating the image with lines of the right height.

Total hack, I know, but it'd work 100% of the time and be blazing fast on rendering.

Comment: Too much of a hack to implement, but that would work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that works automatically to repair the AlternatingItemStyle on invisible items, neither for DataGrid nor for GridView(so far as i know).

So you can repair it manually, for example in the following way:

```
Private visibleRowIndex As Int32 = -1
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        hide/show the GridViewRow according to your business-logic'
        If e.Row.Visible Then
            visibleRowIndex += 1
            e.Row.CssClass = If(visibleRowIndex Mod 2 = 0, "GridRowStyle", "GridAlternatingRowStyle")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit: i've forgotten that you are using the DataGrid:

```
Private visibleRowIndex As Int32 = -1
Protected Sub DataGridItem_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse _
         e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        'show/hide the DataGridItem according to your business-logic'
        If e.Item.Visible Then
            visibleRowIndex += 1
            e.Item.CssClass = If(visibleRowIndex Mod 2 = 0, "GridRowStyle", "GridAlternatingRowStyle")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't want to do it manually, but without a hack it looks like logic similar to this is what has to be done.  I just put it into an extension method. +1